# Electrum & BitAddress Wallets Creation

Tags: wallet, electrum, currencies, paper-wallet, bitaddress.org

Can anyone please tell me if my procedure is correct and enough.
I've always heard and read that I must disconnect from the internet when creating Electrum Wallets, to keep away from hacks, viruses, malware or having my bitcoins stolen.

I have created electrum wallets and bitaddress paper wallets yesterday. Though I dont know much about its technicalities, I just followed simple procedures I've read online.

1. downloaded electrum exe installer and bitaddress (from github)
2. save them in my usb
3. disconnected my laptop from the internet
4. uninstall and reinstall Windows 10 (I have windows installation files too, in my usb)
5. created Electrum wallet, write the seed in a paper. save the wallet file in my usb.
6. created bitaddress paper wallet, write the Public Key and Private Key in a paper (not print). have checked the spellings, capitalizations multiple times.
7. uninstall and reinstall windows 10 again, scanned my usb, then connect again to the internet.

Thanks for any advice / clarifications,
Elena

Comment: Why generate the bitaddress paper wallet? Besides the other issues that have made paper wallets somewhat obsolete, writing down the private keys manually is generally a terrible idea-- using an HD wallet mnemonic phrase as physical backup is a **much** less error-prone method of achieving the same goal.

Comment: Also, if you're downloading a binary electrum file, you should have a step to check the pgp sigs on that file, to ensure you're getting the authentic software signed by the project developers. There have been instances of malicious versions of electrum being distributed, leading to users losing funds.

Comment: If errors in paper wallets Public Address and Private Key is a concern,  I am 100% sure that I got it correctly written (checked multiple times, written multiple times to make sure all the outputs are 100% matched.). By the other concern (somewhat obsolete), please enlighten me about the matter. Thanks.

Comment: @coiners98bit https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Paper_wallet